# Sharing Variables Between Colorbox(s) Loading different pages - Where does the return variable go?

Tags: jquery, dom, colorbox

I have a page with a link that opens a standard colorbox window(1) which is a record summary. On the page displayed inside of colorbox, I have several more links that will open selection pages where a user can pick a person or a status and save it back to the summary form. These links are also designed to open in the colorbox window(2), here is the function:

```
    function makeColorboxMES(mes) {
        if (mes == 'changeLog') {
            href = '/RootDirectory/MyReport/ChangeLog.aspx;
        }
        if(mes == 'employeeByName') {
            href = '/RootDirectory/MyReport/EmployeeByName.aspx?Val=Name;
        }
        if (mes == 'getStatus') {
            href = '/RootDirectory/MyReport/SelectStatus.aspx?Val=Status;
        }
        parent.$.fn.colorbox({ iframe: true, href: href, width: '70%', height: '70%', escKey: true, inline: false, showClose: true, overlayClose: false, onLoad: function () { $('#cboxClose').hide() } }); 
    }
```

After the user has made their selection, there is a javascript function on the master page that is supposed to capture their choice, it looks like this:

```
    function restartList() {
        if (Val == 'Status') {
                $('[id$=status]').val(Codename);
                $('[id$=hidStatus]').val(CodeNumber);
        }
    }
```

The selection page itself is working correctly and sending out the variable but the master page javascript function never fires. I believed that this was because the original colorbox window is still open. So I tried moving the code to the actual remaining colorbox page that's still open but that doesn't fire either. Can someone help me understand exactly where in the DOM my data is being returned to?

Comment: Sorry, just realized that I forgot to add that the call that sends the data to the master page looks like this: getparent().restartList();

Comment: I found the answer to my question, while I thought I was opening two distinctly separate windows, it was in fact just overwriting the old colorbox window with the new data, so there was nothing to talk to though it appeared that it was because it was reloading the old page but in a new iframe. Did some testing and it looks like a possible workaround is to load the iframes into divs on the page and then call the divs into the colorbox. Appeared to initially work.